# I get an error when creating a job collection using Azure SDK

Tags: azure, sdk, scheduler

The error message is 
BadRequest: The condition specified by the ETag is not satisfied.

this is the code i am using

```
   _cloudServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudServiceName"];
            _maxJobCount = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxJobCount"]);


            string certpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/DanAzureCertificate.pfx");

            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certpath, "SOLID");

            CertificateCloudCredentials creds = new CertificateCloudCredentials(_subScriptionID, cert);

            smClient = new SchedulerManagementClient(creds);

            smClient.LongRunningOperationInitialTimeout = int.MaxValue;



            schedulerClient = new SchedulerClient(_cloudServiceName, "", creds);

            schedulerClient.LongRunningOperationInitialTimeout = int.MaxValue;


 JobCollectionCreateParameters pc = new JobCollectionCreateParameters();
                    pc.IntrinsicSettings = new JobCollectionIntrinsicSettings();
                    pc.IntrinsicSettings.Quota = new JobCollectionQuota();
                    pc.IntrinsicSettings.Quota.MaxJobCount = _maxJobCount;
                    pc.IntrinsicSettings.Plan = JobCollectionPlan.Standard;

                    pc.Label = jobCollectionName; 
                    //   smClient = new SchedulerManagementClient();

                    smClient.LongRunningOperationInitialTimeout = 3600;


                    var createreposnse = smClient.JobCollections.Create(_cloudServiceName, jobCollectionName, pc);
```

this is  what i get in the output windows

The thread 0x2524 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.ac922776334349f8bcc2e2ed951af0a9.RemoteDependency","time":"2017-01-14T12:13:41.2610531Z","iKey":"ac922776-3343-49f8-bcc2-e2ed951af0a9","tags":{"ai.device.roleInstance":"HP","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf: 2.1.0.363"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"https://management.core.windows.net/c44db09b-bb78-417c-a130-934ce4edb2f5/cloudservices/newCloudService/resources/scheduler/~/JobCollections/JC1","id":"e9odaNEE8sI=","value":1888.9979,"resultCode":"404","dependencyKind":1,"success":false,"properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
Exception thrown: 'Hyak.Common.CloudException' in Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
Application Insights Telemetry: {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.ac922776334349f8bcc2e2ed951af0a9.RemoteDependency","time":"2017-01-14T12:13:48.7034807Z","iKey":"ac922776-3343-49f8-bcc2-e2ed951af0a9","tags":{"ai.device.roleInstance":"HP","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf: 2.1.0.363"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"https://management.core.windows.net/c44db09b-bb78-417c-a130-934ce4edb2f5/cloudservices/newCloudService/resources/scheduler/JobCollections/JC1","id":"2Y8TsJ/Dv/Y=","value":1418.5722,"resultCode":"400","dependencyKind":1,"success":false,"properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
Exception thrown: 'Hyak.Common.CloudException' in Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131288695585980488): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[11560] iisexpress.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[11560] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[9564] iexplore.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: do you have any additional messages at the Azure Portal? did you try to create this job collection via Portal?

Comment: yes  from  the portal works seamless .  This code used to work a few days ago , not sure what happened .

Comment: I think the region can be an issue.

Comment: i m not sure what do you mean by region here  , is there a way to solve it ?